# PHP references inside the constructor

Tags: php, constructor, reference

I would like to built 'Main' class, where call another class.

```
<?php

class Main {

    private $admin;

    function __constructor(){

        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoLoad'));
        $this->admin = new AdminFrontEnd();
    }

    function autoLoad($class) {
        include $class.'.php';
    }

    function debug($s){

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($s);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    function teszt(){

       echo $this->admin->kiir('debug content');


    }
```

This code throw an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function kiir() on a non-object in Classes/Main.php on line 28

How to set more class call in constructor ? eg:

```
function __constructor(){

    /* ... */
    $this->admin = new AdminFrontEnd();
    $this->invoice = new InvoiceGenerate();
    $this->pdf = new GeneratePDF();
    /* etc ... */
}

function getPDF(){

    return $this->pdf->getPDFLocation();

}

/* etc function ... */
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious and I am ashamed that I did not spot it earlier...

```
function __constructor(){...}
```

should be:

```
function __construct(){...}
```

make this modification and it will work.

ALSO: in case you need it:

```
function __destruct(){..} //not __destructor()
```

Take care!

Comment: accept me if I'm right :))

Comment: .... I can't imagine that ... how don't spot this when I'm wrote this code.

Comment: don't beat yourself about it... happens more than you think ;)

Comment: no problem man! Anytime :)